# d3: how to avoid interpolation / splines of curve

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955, the curves are interpolated / calculated by some spline algorithm (just to get round curves).

How do I have to change the example to get angular shaped curves?

Comment: Remove this line: `.curve(d3.curveBasis)`. This is the result: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/941b69c54ac26e0210758bad337545fc

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thank you!